# In online correspondence chess, are the ratings adjustments based on the pre- or post-game ratings?

Tags: rating, elo, correspondence-chess

When playing rated online correspondence chess, it's quite possible that the players' ratings change during the game. When the game is over, which rating will be used for rating adjustments? The ratings they had before the game began, or the rating at the end of the game?

Comment: Do you mean ICCF games?

Comment: Not necessarily, I meant any kind of (online) correspondence chess.

Answer (score 1):

Every site that I have seen uses the rating at the end of the game.

Comment: But GameKnot doesn't: it uses either the rating at start of the game or the rating at the end of the game, whichever is higher.

Answer (score 1):

Online sites use the rating at the beginning of the game. You can tell that because that's the rating they display even if it's changed.